# Convert in bash pipe does not work as wanted

Tags: bash, imagemagick-convert

Not sure if this is convert problem or bash, since I have not seen similar issue in other bash scripts.

Core script as following. The $text is "( img,white30.png,0,0,30,30 img,white30.png,560,320,30,30 3℃ img,iconall.png,0,0,24,24 img,iconall.png,200,0,24,24 '<3级' )". The result is supposed to be a $color-ed roundrectangle, with "image image 3℃ image image <3级" (no space) on it.

If I manually execute the logic, all fine. But when I run the script with -x, I got a confusing sequence of commands (see the last part of the question) and result picture (The 3℃ part is just blank with seems-about-right place held).

```
convert -size "${w}x${h}" canvas:transparent -fill "${color}" -draw "roundrectangle 0,0,${w},${h},15,15" "PNG32:${iPic}"

local x=0
for i in "${text[@]}"; do
    if [[ "${i}" == img,* ]]; then
        IFS=, read -r img filename x1 y1 w1 h1 <<< "${i}"
        convert "${filename}" -crop "${w1}x${h1}+${x1}+${y1}" - |
        convert "${iPic}" - -gravity northwest -geometry "+${x}+$(( (h - h1) / 2 ))" -composite "${oPic}"
    else
        local wxh
        wxh="$(textSize "${i}")"
        w1="$(cut -dx -f1 <<< "${wxh}")"
        convert -size "${w}x${h}" canvas:black -fill white -draw "roundrectangle 0,0,${w},${h},15,15" PNG32:- |
        convert - canvas:white -fill black -pointsize 40 -font Noto-Sans-Mono-CJK-SC-Regular -gravity northwest -annotate "+${x}+0" "${i}" PNG32:- |
        convert "${iPic}" - -alpha Off -compose CopyOpacity -composite "${oPic}"
    fi
    x=$(( x + w1 ))
    cp -f "${oPic}" "${iPic}"
done
convert "${src}" "${oPic}" -gravity "${gravity}" -geometry "${position}" -composite "${dest}"
```

bash -x output (only calls to convert):

```
+++ convert -debug annotate xc: -font Noto-Sans-Mono-CJK-SC-Regular -pointsize 40 -annotate 0 3℃ null:
+++ convert -debug annotate xc: -font Noto-Sans-Mono-CJK-SC-Regular -pointsize 40 -annotate 0 '<3级' null:
+ convert -size 254x59 canvas:transparent -fill '#8fa6bc' -draw 'roundrectangle 0,0,254,59,15,15' PNG32:/tmp/tmp.zBBu2pNx1h
+ convert white30.png -crop 30x30+0+0 -
+ convert /tmp/tmp.zBBu2pNx1h - -gravity northwest -geometry +0+14 -composite /tmp/tmp.lPXXH4jNsW
+ convert white30.png -crop 30x30+560+320 -
+ convert /tmp/tmp.zBBu2pNx1h - -gravity northwest -geometry +30+14 -composite /tmp/tmp.lPXXH4jNsW
+++ convert -debug annotate xc: -font Noto-Sans-Mono-CJK-SC-Regular -pointsize 40 -annotate 0 3℃ null:
+ convert -size 254x59 canvas:black -fill white -draw 'roundrectangle 0,0,254,59,15,15' PNG32:-
+ convert - canvas:white -fill black -pointsize 40 -font Noto-Sans-Mono-CJK-SC-Regular -gravity northwest -annotate +60+0 3℃ PNG32:-
+ convert /tmp/tmp.zBBu2pNx1h - -alpha Off -compose CopyOpacity -composite /tmp/tmp.lPXXH4jNsW
+ convert iconall.png -crop 24x24+0+0 -
+ convert /tmp/tmp.zBBu2pNx1h - -gravity northwest -geometry +122+17 -composite /tmp/tmp.lPXXH4jNsW
+ convert iconall.png -crop 24x24+200+0 -
+ convert /tmp/tmp.zBBu2pNx1h - -gravity northwest -geometry +146+17 -composite /tmp/tmp.lPXXH4jNsW
+++ convert -debug annotate xc: -font Noto-Sans-Mono-CJK-SC-Regular -pointsize 40 -annotate 0 '<3级' null:
+ convert -size 254x59 canvas:black -fill white -draw 'roundrectangle 0,0,254,59,15,15' PNG32:-
+ convert - canvas:white -fill black -pointsize 40 -font Noto-Sans-Mono-CJK-SC-Regular -gravity northwest -annotate +170+0 '<3级' PNG32:-
+ convert /tmp/tmp.zBBu2pNx1h - -alpha Off -compose CopyOpacity -composite /tmp/tmp.lPXXH4jNsW
+ convert - /tmp/tmp.lPXXH4jNsW -gravity southeast -geometry +0+300 -composite -
```

Comment: Please give the simplest, **complete** command you can. The one you show doesn't provide the necessary input on `stdin` and it includes variables whose value is unknown to us.

Comment: Not sure which exact characters you are using... `printf "22\xe2\x84\x83" | convert ...` maybe?

Comment: Could be the shell's LANG setting. Does `echo -e "\xE2\x84\x83"` display the right character?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. After some testing, the result is confusing. This may be something related to bash script. So I will update the question and add bash tag.

Comment: Shell has many pitfalls. I suggest to use another script language to do that work. Why not perl or python? I remember that ImageMagick provide nice API for these languages (PerlMagick and PythonMagick).

Comment: Please make a sensible, simple example. You are showing a whole load of unnecessary stuff that doesn't even match the trace you provide! In doing so, I suspect you will find the answer. Something like I suggested earlier.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried shrink the script to fixed values and so, then it worked. So this whole script does not work as expected. I cannot say which part causes the issue.

Comment: Try adding a line immediately above `fi` that says `echo -e "${i}" | xxd`

Comment: @Jezz Ye, another language might be next step.

Comment: @MarkSetchell You mean check output of every round? Yes, did that. With this script, 3℃ step produced the same as last step.